Error running `cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --features wasm --release` to generate WASM containing only functions declared by macro
So, I'm trying to learn how to create a library. The library I'm working on provides macros to define API request functions. Then, the macro is used in a Rust project (main.rs). When I run cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --features wasm --release, I want only the functions declared by the macro to be compiled to WebAssembly. Then, if I run cargo build --release, I want the macro code to be ignored and excluded from the binary. The generated WebAssembly will be used in the frontend. However, when I run cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --features wasm --release, I get an error like this. Does anyone know how to resolve it?
Update: I'm in Windows OS when building this project
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::IoSourceState`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:14:5
   |
14 | use crate::sys::IoSourceState;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `IoSourceState` in `sys`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::tcp`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:17:17
   |
17 | use crate::sys::tcp::{bind, listen, new_for_addr};
   |                 ^^^ could not find `tcp` in `sys`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::tcp`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:15:17
   |
15 | use crate::sys::tcp::{connect, new_for_addr};
   |                 ^^^ could not find `tcp` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Selector` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\poll.rs:321:18
    |
321 |             sys::Selector::new().map(|selector| Poll {
    |                  ^^^^^^^^ could not find `Selector` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:24:14
   |
24 |         sys::event::token(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:38:14
   |
38 |         sys::event::is_readable(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:43:14
   |
43 |         sys::event::is_writable(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:68:14
   |
68 |         sys::event::is_error(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:99:14
   |
99 |         sys::event::is_read_closed(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:129:14
    |
129 |         sys::event::is_write_closed(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:151:14
    |
151 |         sys::event::is_priority(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:173:14
    |
173 |         sys::event::is_aio(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:183:14
    |
183 |         sys::event::is_lio(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:221:26
    |
221 |                     sys::event::debug_details(f, self.0)
    |                          ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `tcp` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:105:18
    |
105 |             sys::tcp::accept(inner).map(|(stream, addr)| (TcpStream::from_std(stream), addr))
    |                  ^^^ could not find `tcp` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `udp` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\udp.rs:124:14
    |
124 |         sys::udp::bind(addr).map(UdpSocket::from_std)
    |              ^^^ could not find `udp` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `udp` in `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\udp.rs:546:14
    |
546 |         sys::udp::only_v6(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^ could not find `udp` in `sys`

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Selector` in module `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\poll.rs:272:20
    |
272 |     selector: sys::Selector,
    |                    ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Selector` in module `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\poll.rs:728:44
    |
728 |     pub(crate) fn selector(&self) -> &sys::Selector {
    |                                            ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Waker` in module `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\waker.rs:79:17
   |
79 |     inner: sys::Waker,
   |                 ^^^^^ not found in `sys`
   |
help: consider importing one of these structs
   |
1  + use crate::Waker;
   |
1  + use std::task::Waker;
   |
help: if you import `Waker`, refer to it directly
   |
79 -     inner: sys::Waker,
79 +     inner: Waker,
   |

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Waker` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\waker.rs:87:14
   |
87 |         sys::Waker::new(registry.selector(), token).map(|inner| Waker { inner })
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `Waker` in `sys`
   |
help: consider importing one of these structs
   |
1  + use crate::Waker;
   |
1  + use std::task::Waker;
   |
help: if you import `Waker`, refer to it directly
   |
87 -         sys::Waker::new(registry.selector(), token).map(|inner| Waker { inner })
87 +         Waker::new(registry.selector(), token).map(|inner| Waker { inner })
   |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Event` in module `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:18:17
   |
18 |     inner: sys::Event,
   |                 ^^^^^ not found in `sys`
   |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
   |
1  + use crate::event::Event;
   |
help: if you import `Event`, refer to it directly
   |
18 -     inner: sys::Event,
18 +     inner: Event,
   |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Event` in module `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:187:55
    |
187 |     pub(crate) fn from_sys_event_ref(sys_event: &sys::Event) -> &Event {
    |                                                       ^^^^^ not found in `sys`
    |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
    |
1   + use crate::event::Event;
    |
help: if you import `Event`, refer to it directly
    |
187 -     pub(crate) fn from_sys_event_ref(sys_event: &sys::Event) -> &Event {
187 +     pub(crate) fn from_sys_event_ref(sys_event: &Event) -> &Event {
    |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Event` in module `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:191:41
    |
191 |             &*(sys_event as *const sys::Event as *const Event)
    |                                         ^^^^^ not found in `sys`
    |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
    |
1   + use crate::event::Event;
    |
help: if you import `Event`, refer to it directly
    |
191 -             &*(sys_event as *const sys::Event as *const Event)
191 +             &*(sys_event as *const Event as *const Event)
    |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Event` in module `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\event.rs:217:46
    |
217 |             struct EventDetails<'a>(&'a sys::Event);
    |                                              ^^^^^ not found in `sys`
    |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
    |
1   + use crate::event::Event;
    |
help: if you import `Event`, refer to it directly
    |
217 -             struct EventDetails<'a>(&'a sys::Event);
217 +             struct EventDetails<'a>(&'a Event);
    |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Events` in module `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\events.rs:43:17
   |
43 |     inner: sys::Events,
   |                 ^^^^^^ not found in `sys`
   |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
   |
1  + use crate::Events;
   |
help: if you import `Events`, refer to it directly
   |
43 -     inner: sys::Events,
43 +     inner: Events,
   |

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Events` in `sys`
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\events.rs:94:25
   |
94 |             inner: sys::Events::with_capacity(capacity),
   |                         ^^^^^^ could not find `Events` in `sys`
   |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
   |
1  + use crate::Events;
   |
help: if you import `Events`, refer to it directly
   |
94 -             inner: sys::Events::with_capacity(capacity),
94 +             inner: Events::with_capacity(capacity),
   |

error[E0412]: cannot find type `Events` in module `sys`
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\events.rs:189:47
    |
189 |     pub(crate) fn sys(&mut self) -> &mut sys::Events {
    |                                               ^^^^^^ not found in `sys`
    |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
    |
1   + use crate::Events;
    |
help: if you import `Events`, refer to it directly
    |
189 -     pub(crate) fn sys(&mut self) -> &mut sys::Events {
189 +     pub(crate) fn sys(&mut self) -> &mut Events {
    |

error[E0425]: cannot find value `listener` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:76:24
   |
76 |         set_reuseaddr(&listener.inner, true)?;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `listener` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:78:15
   |
78 |         bind(&listener.inner, addr)?;
   |               ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `listener` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:79:17
   |
79 |         listen(&listener.inner, 1024)?;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `listener` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:80:12
   |
80 |         Ok(listener)
   |            ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `stream` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:95:18
   |
95 |         connect(&stream.inner, addr)?;
   |                  ^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `stream` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:96:12
   |
96 |         Ok(stream)
   |            ^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function `set_reuseaddr` in this scope
  --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:76:9
   |
76 |         set_reuseaddr(&listener.inner, true)?;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0599]: no method named `register` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::TcpListener>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:148:20
    |
148 |         self.inner.register(registry, token, interests)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<TcpListener>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `register` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `register`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `reregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::TcpListener>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:157:20
    |
157 |         self.inner.reregister(registry, token, interests)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<TcpListener>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `reregister` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `reregister`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `deregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::TcpListener>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:161:20
    |
161 |         self.inner.deregister(registry)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<TcpListener>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `deregister` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `deregister`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\listener.rs:237:9
    |
237 | /         unsafe {
238 | |             #[cfg(any(unix, target_os = "hermit", target_os = "wasi"))]
239 | |             {
240 | |                 net::TcpListener::from_raw_fd(listener.into_raw_fd())
...   |
245 | |             }
246 | |         }
    | |_________^ expected `TcpListener`, found `()`

error[E0599]: no method named `register` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::TcpStream>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:330:20
    |
330 |         self.inner.register(registry, token, interests)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<TcpStream>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `register` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `register`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `reregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::TcpStream>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:339:20
    |
339 |         self.inner.reregister(registry, token, interests)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<TcpStream>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `reregister` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `reregister`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `deregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::TcpStream>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:343:20
    |
343 |         self.inner.deregister(registry)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<TcpStream>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `deregister` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `deregister`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\tcp\stream.rs:419:9
    |
419 | /         unsafe {
420 | |             #[cfg(any(unix, target_os = "hermit", target_os = "wasi"))]
421 | |             {
422 | |                 net::TcpStream::from_raw_fd(stream.into_raw_fd())
...   |
427 | |             }
428 | |         }
    | |_________^ expected `TcpStream`, found `()`

error[E0599]: no method named `register` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::UdpSocket>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\udp.rs:624:20
    |
624 |         self.inner.register(registry, token, interests)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<UdpSocket>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `register` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `register`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `reregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::UdpSocket>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\udp.rs:633:20
    |
633 |         self.inner.reregister(registry, token, interests)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<UdpSocket>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `reregister` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `reregister`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `deregister` found for struct `IoSource<std::net::UdpSocket>` in the current scope
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\udp.rs:637:20
    |
637 |         self.inner.deregister(registry)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `IoSource<UdpSocket>`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\io_source.rs:37:1
    |
37  | pub struct IoSource<T> {
    | ---------------------- method `deregister` not found for this struct
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Source` defines an item `deregister`, perhaps you need to implement it
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\event\source.rs:75:1
    |
75  | pub trait Source {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\Users\fujis\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mio-1.0.2\src\net\udp.rs:713:9
    |
713 | /         unsafe {
714 | |             #[cfg(any(unix, target_os = "hermit", target_os = "wasi"))]
715 | |             {
716 | |                 net::UdpSocket::from_raw_fd(socket.into_raw_fd())
...   |
721 | |             }
722 | |         }
    | |_________^ expected `UdpSocket`, found `()`

Here are the code :
Cargo.toml (For the library)
[package]
name = "test_makro"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[features]
generate-wasm = []

[dependencies]
syn = { version = "2.0", features = ["full"] }
quote = "1.0"
proc-macro2 = "1.0"
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
web-sys = { version = "0.3", features = [
    "Request",
    "RequestInit",
    "RequestMode",
    "Response",
    "Window",
    "Headers"
]}
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4"

Lib.rs
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, parse::Parse, parse::ParseStream, Result, Type, LitStr, Ident};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum HttpMethod {
    Get,
    Post,
}

impl Parse for HttpMethod {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let ident: Ident = input.parse()?;
        match ident.to_string().to_lowercase().as_str() {
            "get" => Ok(HttpMethod::Get),
            "post" => Ok(HttpMethod::Post),
            _ => Err(syn::Error::new(ident.span(), "Only GET and POST methods are supported")),
        }
    }
}

struct ApiEndpoint {
    fn_name: Ident,
    method: HttpMethod,
    url: LitStr,
    return_type: Type,
}

impl Parse for ApiEndpoint {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        let fn_name = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<syn::Token![,]>()?;
        let method = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<syn::Token![,]>()?;
        let url = input.parse()?;
        input.parse::<syn::Token![,]>()?;
        let return_type = input.parse()?;
        Ok(ApiEndpoint {
            fn_name,
            method,
            url,
            return_type,
        })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn wasm_api(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ApiEndpoint { fn_name, method, url, return_type } = parse_macro_input!(input as ApiEndpoint);
    
    let method_str = match method {
        HttpMethod::Get => "GET",
        HttpMethod::Post => "POST",
    };

    let fetch_code = match method {
        HttpMethod::Get => quote! {
            let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(#url, &opts)
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Failed to create request: {:?}", e)))?;
        },
        HttpMethod::Post => quote! {
            let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(#url, &opts)
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Failed to create request: {:?}", e)))?;
            
            request.headers().set("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Failed to set Content-Type header: {:?}", e)))?;
            
            if let Some(body) = body {
                opts.body(Some(&JsValue::from_str(&body)));
            }
        },
    };
    
    let expanded = quote! {
        #[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]
        #[wasm_bindgen]
        pub async fn #fn_name(body: Option<String>) -> Result<String, JsValue> {
            use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
            use wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture;
            use web_sys::{Request, RequestInit, RequestMode, Response};
            
            let mut opts = RequestInit::new();
            opts.method(#method_str);
            opts.mode(RequestMode::Cors);

            #fetch_code

            request.headers().set("Accept", "application/json")
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Failed to set Accept header: {:?}", e)))?;
            
            let window = web_sys::window()
                .ok_or_else(|| JsValue::from_str("Failed to get window"))?;
            
            let resp_value = JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request))
                .await
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Failed to fetch: {:?}", e)))?;
            
            let resp: Response = resp_value.dyn_into()
                .map_err(|_| JsValue::from_str("Failed to convert response"))?;
            
            let text = JsFuture::from(resp.text()?)
                .await
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Failed to get response text: {:?}", e)))?;
            
            let response_text = text.as_string()
                .ok_or_else(|| JsValue::from_str("Failed to convert response to string"))?;
            
            let _: #return_type = serde_json::from_str(&response_text)
                .map_err(|e| JsValue::from_str(&format!("Invalid JSON response: {:?}", e)))?;
            
            Ok(response_text)
        }

        #[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
        pub fn #fn_name(_body: Option<String>) {
        
        }
    };

    TokenStream::from(expanded)
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn ensure_target(_: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    quote! {
        #[cfg(all(not(target_arch = "wasm32"), feature = "generate-wasm"))]
        compile_error!("'generate-wasm' can only be compiled to target wasm32");
    }.into()
}

Here is the backend that I use for testing the library.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
axum = "0.7.7"
tokio = { version = "1.0", features = ["full"] }
serde_json = "*"
test_makro = { path = "../test-makro" }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }

[features]
default = []
wasm = ["test_makro/generate-wasm"]

Main.rs
use axum::{
    routing::{get, post},
    Json, Router,
};
use test_makro::{wasm_api, ensure_target};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    name: String,
}

wasm_api!(get_users, get, "http://localhost:3000/api/users", User);

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    ensure_target!();

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/api/users", get(get_users_handler))

    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000").await.unwrap();
    println!("Server running on http://0.0.0.0:3000");
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
}

async fn get_users_handler() -> Json<Vec<User>> {
    let users = vec![
        User {
            name: "Hello".to_string(),
        },
    ];
    Json(users)
}


The errors don't look related to your macro - you have a dependency on tokio with "full" which won't work on WASM as per this answer: Can tokio::runtime be used in wasm?

Thank you! Now it can be built by setting the features in the Cargo.toml to exclude axum and tokio when in wasm feature mode. However, when used in the frontend, I get this error : localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="__wbindgen_placeholder__": module is not an object or function. Why is it not an object or function?

I have closed your question since the problem was solved by an existing Q&A. You can post a new question with that error as the focus - however be mindful that a quick search for that error yields existing resources that you should try first.
